# Como montar XML com C#?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2015

Preciso montar um XML como no exemplo a seguir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<MeuXML>
   <Clientes>  
        <Cliente-1>Dados Cliente-1</Cliente>  
   </Clientes> 
   <Sistemas>   
        <Sistema-1>
            <Pasta>Pasta do Sistema-1</Pasta>
            <Origem>Origem do Sistema-1</Fontes>    
        </Sistema-1>
   </Sistemas>
</MeuXMl>
```

Até consigo montar um XML inicial vazio, mas quando vou adicionar um novo cliente por exemplo (como o Cliente-1), meu código duplica a tag de Clientes.
A mesma coisa acontece com os sistemas. Estou fazendo dessa forma com os sistemas (exemplo do Sistema-1):

```
 XElement xml = XElement.Load("Config.xml")
 XElement xmlSistemas = XElement.Load("Config.xml").Elements("Sistemas").FirstOrDefault();
 XElement xSistema1 = new XElement("Sistema-1");
 XElement xPasta = new XElement("Pasta");
 xPasta.Value = "Pasta do Sistema-1";
 XElement xOrigem = new XElement("Origem");
 xOrigem.Value = "Origem do Sistema-1";
 xSistema1.Add(xPasta, xOrigem);
 xmlSistemas.Add(xSistema1);
 xml.Add(xmlSistemas);
 xml.Save("Config.xml");
```

Como posso consertar isso? Obrigado!

Comment: Como `duplica a tag de clientes`? Poste como fica o XML e o código que estás utilizando pra adicionar um cliente...

Comment: O exemplo do código é pra tag de sistemas que está acontecendo a mesma coisa que com os clientes. Dentro do XML eu tenho a tag <MeuXML> e dentro dela as tags <Clientes> e <Sistemas>, depois que eu executo o código que adicionei ao post a tag <Sistemas> aparece duas vezes, sendo que eu preciso que aparece uma única vez, entendeu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está adicionando o tag `<Sistemas>` (e seus filhos) que você criou no arquivo xml (tag MeuXML), que já tem uma tag `Sistemas` - então você fica com duas. O que você precisa fazer é adicionar o novo sistema (`xSistema1`) no tag `Sistemas` que já existe no arquivo. O código abaixo mostra como isso pode ser feito.

```
class Program
{
    const string XML = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?> 
<MeuXML>
   <Clientes>  
        <Cliente-1>Dados Cliente-1</Cliente-1>  
   </Clientes> 
   <Sistemas>   
        <Sistema-1>
            <Pasta>Pasta do Sistema-1</Pasta>
            <Origem>Origem do Sistema-1</Origem>    
        </Sistema-1>
   </Sistemas>
</MeuXML>";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement xml = XElement.Parse(XML);
        XElement xmlSistemas = xml.Elements("Sistemas").FirstOrDefault();
        XElement xSistema2 = new XElement("Sistema-2");
        XElement xPasta = new XElement("Pasta");
        xPasta.Value = "Pasta do Sistema-2";
        XElement xOrigem = new XElement("Origem");
        xOrigem.Value = "Origem do Sistema-2";
        xSistema2.Add(xPasta, xOrigem);
        xmlSistemas.Add(xSistema2);
        Console.WriteLine(xml);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas como eu salvo em um arquivo? Tipo, depois de xmlSistemas.Add(xSistema2); eu devo adicionar a linha xml.Save("Config.xml")?

Comment: Sim, pode salvar de volta. Este aqui é só um exemplo completo (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que ilustra a solução do problema.